# Initializer fails to determine size of errror

Tags: c++, variables, arduino, uint8t

I'm new to a little new to programming, how do I store a variable in `message`? I'm trying to make a wireless temperature sensor using LoRa, with an Arduino Uno + Dragino shield. The results to be displayed on the things network. Everything else is working fine. Why do I get the error written below? `{temp}` does not work either.

CODE:

```
int temp = 25;

// Payload to send (uplink)

static uint8_t message[] = temp;
```

Error:

```
HelloWorld1:77: error: initializer fails to determine size of 'message'

   static uint8_t message[] = temp;
                  ^

HelloWorld1:77: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Multiple libraries were found for "lmic.h"
 Used: C:\Users\\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino-lmic-master
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\arduino-lmic-master
exit status 1
initializer fails to determine size of 'message'
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has to know the size of the array when you declare it. It can find it out either directly from the value in `[]` (e.g. `uint8_t message [2]`) either, if there isn’t any value there, from the length of a braced-enclosed initializer, i.e. the list of comma-separated values inside a `{ }` that you may assign to the array at declaration.

That aside, you can’t directly store an int value (2 bytes, signed) in an uint8_t (1 byte, unsigned). Since (I suppose) you need to transmit data as an uint8_t array you can do as follows:

```
int temp = 25;
// store temp in a uint8_t array with two elements (needed to store two bytes)
uint8_t message[2];
 message[0] = temp >> 8; // Most significant byte, MSB
 message[1] = temp; // Least significant byte, LSB
```

or

```
int temp = 25;
// store temp in a uint8_t array with two elements (needed to store two bytes)
uint8_t message[2] = {(temp >> 8), temp};

 message[0] = temp >> 8; // Most significant byte, MSB
 message[1] = temp; // Least significant byte, LSB
```

Theb transmit `message`, and on the receiver “reconvert” it to an int: `temp = (message[0] << 8) | message[1];`.